# Bloomberg API - How to get user entitlements for user subscription

Tags: api, subscription, bloomberg, entitlements

i'm just trying to check user entitlements for user subscription data from bloomberg api's data feeds.

For this i tried to run Bloombergs example "EntitlementsVerificationSubscriptionExample". As it seems to be working at first sight, on second sight i recognized, that there aren't any entitlements for the data i receive from the api.

that means:

```
public void processSubscriptionDataEvent(Event eventObj, Session session)
        {

            foreach(Message msg in eventObj)
            {

                bool needsEntitlement = msg.HasElement(Name.GetName("EID"));   
            }

             }
```

is always 'false', as there is never a field called "EID" available.

Is there something wrong on bloomberg service site or better, is there any kind of documentation available, how to use user entitlements within data subscriptions?

thanks in advance,

Comment: I have some code that does this: `Element returnedEids = response.getElement("eids"); int numeids = returnedEids.numValues(); for (int i = 0; i < numeids; ++i) result.addPermission(returnedEids.getValueAsInt32(i));`. So it looks like it is using `eids` instead of `eid`.

Comment: hm no, there is also no field "eids", there isn't even any field with a name containing "EID" in the whole message.

or is my message of type "Event.EventType.SUBSCRIPTION_DATA" not enabled for checking user entitlements?

Comment: The code I'm referring to parses the result of a `UserEntitlementsRequest` request  that has been sent to the `//blp/apiauth`. So maybe not what you are looking for.

Comment: UserEntitlementsRequest is deprecated in Api V3 and should not be used to get user entitlements.The only way (and the right way) is to extract user's EID's from user identity object. The list is not directly exposed to the Api at the time of this writing, however, there is a workaround to achieve this. In most cases you will not need the list of user EIDs.

Comment: Also, the above code snippet from assylias works only for Response message, but not with subscription data.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to subscribe to the "EID" field, as it's not returned by default.

If the field either is not returned in the message, or had Null value, then that means data in this message does not require entitlements. Otherwise, call the following function and pass the EID value:

```
bool bEntitled = userIdentity.hasEntitlements(EID);
```

Function return value indicates whether user is entitled or not.

Data that does not require entitlements can be shared with users who are registered in EMRS (in case of B-Pipe), or with any terminal user within the firm (in case of SAPI) with no further entitlement check. Users who are not registered in EMRS or those who are non-terminal users should not have access to either B-Pipe data, or SAPI data, respectively.

Comment: thanks! Changed the result, but there is still no EID field present. But if i request the EID field, the amount of provided fields reduces from about 870 to 92.


               `new Subscription("SOME_Equity", "LAST_PRICE, EID", null, new CorrrelationID("SOME_Equity"))`


i assume my subscription is done right?

Anyway, i cannot imagine that the realtime data is available to each user? (As i don't need to be authenticated to receive those fields?)

Comment: There are many things in your reply that need to be addressed separately:

1. You had mentioned "user entitlements" on your first post, which imply you are connecting to SAPI or B-Pipe, not DAPI. Please confirm.

2. If you are connecting to SAPI or B-Pipe then are you passing an identity object to session.Subscribe()? If yes, is that identity for User or Application?

Comment: 3. Subscribing to EID should not "reduce" the amount of returned fields. Typically you will receive more fields than you subscribe to, but you should only use values from your fields only. There is no guarantee the other fields will be returned each time. If Field Filtering is is enabled in B-Pipe then you should receive the fields you subscribed to only.

Comment: 4. After calling session.Subscribe() you should get either SubscriptionStarted or SubscriptionFailure message in SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS event. That is the only way to know if your subscription is valid. If subscription starts then 
 you should receive Initial Paint - please subscribe to MKTDATA_EVENT_TYPE and MKTDATA_EVENT_SUBTYPE fields to get more info on message contents. I also recommend to subscribe to IS_DELAYED_STREAM.

Comment: 5. I you connect yo SAPI or B-Pipe while not passing any identity then that means your instance allows Server Mode. In this case you still need to perform Entitlement Check to remain Compliant!

6. It would help if you could share code snippet of how you call session.Subscribe() and the output. This will help me better understand the issue.

Comment: 1. I "think" i'm using SAPI (but i'm not fully sure about that)
2. I do not provide any identity to the api, as the application just transforms the data, user entitlements should be checked by the "next" application in chain.
4.  Subscription Status comes back, message looks like this: 
´SubscriptionStarted = {
    exceptions[] = {
    }
}´

Comment: My subscriptions looks like this: http://codepad.org/6ECre110 for better readability.

Comment: `d_session = new Session(options, new EventHandler(this.processEvent));
            bool sessionStarted = d_session.Start();´ 
d_subscriptions = new List<Subscription>
            {
                new Subscription("BMW GY Equity", "LAST_PRICE, eid, MKTDATA_EVENT_TYPE, MKTDATA_EVENT_SUBTYPE, IS_DELAYED_STREAM", null, new CorrrelationID("BMW GY Equity")),
                new Subscription("ALV GY Equity", "LAST_PRICE, eid, MKTDATA_EVENT_TYPE, MKTDATA_EVENT_SUBTYPE, IS_DELAYED_STREAM", null, new CorrrelationID("ALV GY Equity"))
            };

d_session.Subscribe(d_subscriptions);`

Comment: My first message looks like this:

`Start Event -----------
Processing event of type: SUBSCRIPTION_DATA
Messages found: 1
No necessarcy entitlements found. (REALTIME)
MKTDATA_EVENT_TYPE: MKTDATA_EVENT_TYPE = SUMMARY

MKTDATA_EVENT_SUBTYPE: MKTDATA_EVENT_SUBTYPE = INITPAINT

2018-12-17T10:27:33: BMW GY Equity - MarketDataEvents
Received value for field: LAST_PRICE = value

End Event -----------`

Comment: ah, i'm using the SAPI definitely,  as i connect to a different machine for accessing bloomberg services.

Comment: Thanks.
1. Mostly not important but I'd suggest to use 'EID' (all caps) instead of 'eid'.
2. The output seems to be from your own code. Please print the raw incoming data using msg.ToString() and post the output for few ticks.

Comment: 3. You are not passing any identity to subscription, that means your SAPI allowes Server Mode. You are required to perform Entitlement Check before disseminating data to the users. This is done by calling userIdentity.HasEntitlements(EID) as explained earlier. First you will need to authorize a user identity for each user by calling SendAuthorizationRequest() with user's UUID and IP address of the PC where he/she is logged in to the terminal.

Comment: But i can't check EIDs as the EIDs field is always empty or not available.

The full log with msg.toString() looks like this: http://codepad.org/UFC6R6qy

Comment: I suspect your SAPI is setup for Delayed data which, for most exchanges, are free and don't require entitlement checks, therefore EID field is missing in data messages (I assume you subscribe to EID feild). Can you subscribe to IS_DELAYED_STREAM too and check the returned value, should be boolean either True or False.

Comment: IS_DELAYED_STREAM is available, but just in ~50% of the cases true.

Comment: IS_DELAYED_STREAM = True means this is delayed data and most likely the message will not contain EID or will have EID = blank.

IS_DELAYED_STREAM = False means this is a realtime stream and EID field will always exist and will have value (unless the exchange offers free realtime data)